# Getting sysroot directory with cmake in yocto

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling, yocto

I have a few libraries/applications (supplied by a third party vendor, so changing them is not really an option) that are built in a non standard way. Basically, there are libraries that link to other libraries in a weird way.

Here's what I'm talking about:

```
.
├── libA
│   ├── include
│   │   └── headerA.h
│   └── src
└── libB
    ├── include
    │   └── headerB.h
    └── src
```

`libA` includes `libB` headers using the `""` syntax, i.e. `#include "headerB.h
"` and `-I` compile option is passed to include the `libB/include/` directory. However, linking to `libA` poses a problem, because I need to include `libB` include directory as well.

That's not a huge problem, because the headers get installed into the targets sysroot. Let's say the `libB` headers are installed into `${SYSROOT}/usr/include/libB`.

Now, for some reason the sysroot directory is passed using the `${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}` instead of `${CMAKE_SYSROOT}` as it probably should. I tried parsing `${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}` to get the sysroot like this:

```
execute_process(COMMAND "echo \"${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}\""
        COMMAND "grep -Eo '\\-\\-sysroot=\\S*'"
        COMMAND "sed 's:--sysroot=::g'"
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE SYSROOT
        RESULT_VARIABLE SYSROOT_RESULT
)
```

However, this always fails with `"No such file or directory"`. I figured it's failing to one of the commands, i.e. either `echo`, `grep` or `sed`. How do I fix this? Or maybe there's a better way altogether?

Comment: what you want exactly?

Comment: To get the `--sysroot` variable from `${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}`.

Comment: "I figured it's failing to one of the commands, i.e. either `echo`, `grep` or `sed`. - Have you tried to **debug** which command is failed actually, and why? For debug purposes you may print value of *OUTPUT_VARIABLE* after the call, you may check *RESULT_VARIABLE* after the call and so on. BTW, CMake by itself has functions working with regular expressions: [string(REGEX)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/string.html#regular-expressions). You may try to use those functions instead of external utilities like `grep` and `sed`.